# How add download link php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, video

**i add**

```
"sources": <|php echo $file?>
```

**the resultat**

```
"sources":[{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "HD", "file": "https://video-12345.mp4"}]         }],
```

**i want to add the download button**

```
function() {
    window.location.href = " <|php echo $file?>";
```

**the resultat**

```
function() {
    window.location.href = [{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "HD", "file": "https://video-12345.mp4"}]            }],
```

so i want just the video link?
resultat like this...

```
function() {
    window.location.href = "https://video-12345.mp4";
```

**so i want to make download with 1 click**

Comment: Please show what code you have tried, and clear reproducible code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i don't know anymore how to add the code here :(

Comment: right below your post is an "edit" button you can edit information back into your post

Answer (score 0):

if <|php echo $file?> produces an array of values, then...

```
var data = [{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "HD", "file": "https://video-12345.mp4"}]; // output of <|php echo $file?>

function myFunction() {
    window.location.href = data[0]['file']; // first item in data array, file property value
}
```